# Javadoc: How to make it cross-link the dependencies (Maven project)

Tags: java, dependencies, javadoc

I would like to generate Javadoc which would include the classes of project's dependencies.
For example, project Windup would reference JBoss Forge, TinkerPop Frames and Rewrite.

Can Javadoc do it? How?

If I define the G:A:V -> Javadoc URL, it should be technically doable.

I found about [`javadoc -link`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#linkoffline).

I have also found Maven's [`<detectLinks>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/aggregate-jar-mojo.html) but setting it to `true` made no change.

I've experimentally tried:

```
<additionalparam>-link http://docs.jboss.org/forge/javadoc/2.13.0-SNAPSHOT/</additionalparam>
```

And that works.
However, I'd like to make Maven do this link resolving. Just as the `detectLinks` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about import whole API Docs link into your config. I found it on this site: 
[Import API Docs](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-generate-a-javadoc-report-for-a-site.html)